# Java. getClass() returns a class, how come I can get a string too?

Tags: java

When I use `System.out.println(obj.getClass())` it doesn't give me any error. From what I understand `getClass()` returns a Class type. 
Since `println()` will print only strings, how come instead of a class, `println` is getting a String?

Comment: `obj.getClass().getName()`? or `obj.getClass().toString()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All objects in Java inherit from the class [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). If you look at that document, you'll see that `Object` specifies a `toString` method which converts the object into a String. Since all non-primitive types (including `Class`es) are `Object`s, anything can be converted into a string using its `toString` method.

Classes can *override* this method to provide their own way of being turned into a string. For example, the `String` class overrides `Object.toString` to return itself. `Class` overrides it to return the name of the class. This lets you specify how you want your object to be output.

Answer (score 38):

`System.out.println(someobj)` is always equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(someobj));
```

And, for non-null values of `someobj`, that prints `someobj.toString();`

In your case, you are doing `println(obj.getClass())` so you are really doing:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(obj.getClass()));
```

which is calling the `toString` method on the class.

Comment: +1, most accurate. From the API doc for PrintStream.println( Object ): "This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value ..."

Comment: Sorry for the sub-question, but is there any reason why `String.valueOf()` is used rather than `object.toString()`?  I noticed other parts of the Java API also use `String.valueOf`, whereas I would usually use the latter.

Comment: @jazzbassrob: The standard definition of `String.valueOf(Object obj)` is `return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();`, so it is basically the same thing, plus `null` handling.

Answer (score 4):

See [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28%29):

```
787     public void println(Object x) {
788         String s = String.valueOf(x);
789         synchronized (this) {
790             print(s);
791             newLine();
792         }
793     }
```

Note the `String.valueOf(x)`.

*Bonus* for asking a good question:

```
632     public void print(String s) {
633         if (s == null) {
634             s = "null";
635         }
636         write(s);
637     }
```

That's why it prints `null` when the object is null :)

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, every class in Java inherits from the `Object` class.  This means that every class automatically has the method `toString()`, which returns a representation of the object as a `String`.  When you concatenate a string with an object, or if you pass an `Object` into an argument where there should be a `String`, Java automatically calls the `toString()` method to convert it into a `String`.  In your case, the `toString()` method has been overridden to return the name of the class.

You can see this happen with other objects, too:

```
Set s = new Set();
s.add(1);
s.add(3);
s.add(5);
System.out.println(s);
```

will output "[1, 3, 5]".

Comment: +1, but I would use a different example since `Integer` can be implicitly converted anyway