# System.out.println prints different Strings on the same Object type using getClass()

Tags: java

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385467/java-getclass-returns-a-class-how-come-i-can-get-a-string-too) but I'm not fully satisfied by it.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Car c = new Car();
   System.out.println(c);
   System.out.println(c.getClass());
}
```

Output:

```
Car@xxx
Car
```

And I have not understood why in the first case it prints also the hashCode and it does not in the second. I've seen how `println(Object obj)` is defined and the methods it uses, and they are the same, in fact, at the deepest level of stack calls, `toString()` is defined like this:

```
public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

So why at the output I can't see "@xxx"?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because `c.getClass()` returns a `Class<?>` object, and the class `Class` overrides the `toString` method so that `Class.toString` doesn't do the same thing as `Object.toString`. If it did, you'd see `Class@xxx` instead of `Car@xxx`.

Comment: Thank you guys. The doubt came to me because I did Ctrl+click on println from Eclipse, and it brought me on the method which receives an Object, not a Class. Does it mean that's an error of Eclipse?

Comment: The error is not in Eclipse, but in your expectations.  The behavior is correct.  (The class `Class` overrides the `toString` implementation you have quoted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [getClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) will return the instance of `Class`

```
public final Class<?> getClass()
```

And when you print `Class` instance, toString is called which returns the name, here is the [toString](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java) implementation of `Class` in java

```
public String toString() {
    return (isInterface() ? "interface " : (isPrimitive() ? "" : "class "))
        + getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Class.toString` is defined differently, exactly generating the output you see. It's just printing the class' name. There's no `Object.toString` default in that class ever invoked

Answer (score 1):

In the following statement, `toString()` method of `Car` is called:

```
System.out.println(c);
```

In the following statement, `toString()` method of `Class` is called:

```
System.out.println(c.getClass());
```

Since you haven't overridden the `toString()` method of `Car`, the [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method of `Object` is getting called giving you output like `Car@xxx`.